# Throwing Authorization Failed error while access through svn+ssh after enabling path-based authorization

Tags: linux, svn, rhel7

I have setup an SVN server on RHEL 7.2 machine with in-built RPM. After I have created a repository.

After the creation of the repository `demorepo`, I was successful in accessing the repository in one client through `'svn+ssh'` protocol using `'root'` user.

But later I enabled path-based authorization and configured the svnserve.conf, passwd and authz files of the repository as below:

svnserve.conf file

```
anon-access = none
auth-access = write
password-db = passwd
authz-db = authz
```

passwd file

```
rouser1 = pswd1
rouser2 = pswd2
rwuser1 = pswd3
rwuser2 = pswd4
spluser = pswd5
```

authz file

```
[groups]
readgrp = rouser1,rouser2,spluser
writegrp = rwuser1,rwuser2

[demorepo:/]
@readgrp = r
@writegrp = rw

[demorepo:/proj1]
spluser = rw

[demorepo:/proj2]
spluser =
```

Now, after the configuration of the above files, I am successful in accessing the repository through the `"svn"` protocol (not through the ssh tunnel) but I lost the access through the `"svn+ssh"` protocol.

So, is there any way to access the repository with the both the protocols simultaneously while path-based authorization is enabled? Or please let me know if I had done any mistake in my configuration?

Comment: Please reply with any solution urgently. If any one who went through this query could not understand please let me know.

Comment: Have you managed to use svn+ssh for any user other than root before switching on path based authorization?

Answer (score 0):

mostly it is path issue .

if you are using same path for svn and 'svn+ssh' then that the issue as ssh will take full path so if we assume /proj1 is located in

**/home/user/project1**

the **svn+ssh** path will be **yoursite.com/home/user/project1**

while the **svn** path is **yoursite.com/project1**

Comment: Thank you Hani for the response. I am sure that the path was entered correctly. I just found the difference like this. I was using svn+ssh perfectly until then and just when uncommented the line "authz-db = authz", it stopped working and when I again commented it worked back. So, I understand from this that when the file <repository>/conf/authz is being read then I could not connect through svn+ssh while I am successful in using path-based authorization and connect through just svn without ssh.